# config files and referencing config values inside of them

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have two projects FOO and BAR

Inside of BAR i have a class

```
public static class CheckInServiceFactory
{
    public static ICheckInService GetInstance()
    {
        var factory = new ChannelFactory<ICheckInService>("CheckInService");
        return factory.CreateChannel();
    }
}
```

Inside of FOO i have the calling code

```
var searchResults = CheckInServiceFactory.GetInstance();
```

Also inside of FOO I have an appconfig which has "CheckInService" endpoint set up.

**My question is, How does the CheckInServiceFactory know to lookin in FOO's appconfig for the endpoint?**

**Why doesn't it look for it in BAR's config file (which btw its not there so i thought this would blow up)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All configuration files are always in the executing application. If that's an .EXE file of some sort, then they are in *application*.exe.config. If it's a web application, then that's web.config.

Library files' (.dll) config are never used.

It has been that way since Day 1.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration comes from the application config file.

I presume FOO is the app and BAR is a referenced dll. So the config would be read from FOO.exe.config

Comment: yup FOO is the app and BAR is the reference.